# Support for special german characters in Search

Tags: search, i18n-l10n

We are creating search for a German language website. Search should support German special characters, e.g. "ß" is generally also written as "ss". A search for the name "Meißner" should also return results for "Meissner" and vice versa.

Is there any existing solution for this?